# Is there an Old English word meaning RAPIDS or RIFFLE (a rocky shoal causing a rapid)?

Tags: old-english

I would like to find an old (Old English) word meaning "a place in a river where the water overflows a natural stone or rocky obstacle situated across the entire watercourse".

See the picture below.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Autor: Витольд Муратов – <span class="int-own-work">Fotografie je vlastním dílem</span>, <a title="Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY-SA 3.0</a>, <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=10954377">Odkaz</a>]

Comment: Try asking [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/)